# cfnInclude error in cdk v2 - Resource 'uses Condition that doesn't exist

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I am trying to include custom resources in my CDK template using below. The Condition in my resource is the one which exists in main template (using new.core.cfnCondition). However, during execution (synthesis), I get the below error. :

```
        new CfnInclude(this, 'customResources', { templateFile: </path/to/below/customresource.json>,  preserveLogicalIds: false})
```

```
Error: Resource 'Bucket' uses Condition 'IsBucketEmpty' that doesn't exist
    at CfnParser.handleAttributes (..\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\core\lib\helpers-internal\cfn-parse.js:1:4828)
```

Below is the custom resource I am trying to include using cfnInclude

```
// customresource.json
```

```
{
      "Resources": {
      "Bucket": {
        "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
        "Condition": "IsBucketEmpty",
        "Properties": {
          "BucketName": "some-bucket-name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I also tried to vend them as a CDK construct, but gives me the same error.                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                         
In many cases, there are existing CloudFormation templates that are not entire applications, but more like specialized fragments, implementing a particular pattern or best practice. If you have templates like that, you can use the CfnInclude class to vend them as CDK Constructs

Comment: I am able to include the custom resource using cfnResource after parsing the json, instead of using cfnInclude, with the limitation that the cfnConditions as part of my custom resource Json are not being included in the stack, as cfnResourceProps only supports type and properties